# Is it possible to define a column type in DataTable at run time?

Tags: c#, datatable, system.data, system.data.datatable

I would like to create a DataTable but I don't know the types of columns at compile time. Therefore, I would like the columns types to be decided at run-time.

WHAT I'VE TRIED:

First, I get some data from Excel:

```
Type tempCheck = (dynamic)(xlRange.Cells[1, currentColumnsCount] as Excel.Range).Value2.GetType();
```

Then I try to use the type to create a column.

```
myDataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(tempCheck.GetType());
```

I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'tempCheck' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tempCheck` is already a type, so you don't need the `typeof`:

```
myDataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, tempCheck);
```

`typeof` is an operator that is used to get an instance of `System.Type` from a type name, and this is done at compile time.

The error "The type or namespace name 'tempCheck' could not be found" is coming because since `typeof` is looking for a compile-time type, it's literally looking for a type called `tempCheck`, like a class or delegate, etc.

Comment: Look more carefully at the first code example, `tempCheck` is already the type, the correct answer would just be `myDataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, tempCheck);`